# How do I change the MSI Cache location in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, cache, windows-installer

On my Windows 7 x64 machine, I'd like to move the cached MSI files from C:\Windows\Installer (which is on my SSD) to a directory on my regular hard drive. (L:)

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the tool [MoveAndLink](http://bitsum.com/junctionmaster.php) to "move" folder to a different drive:

> *JunctionMaster is a small and simple shell extension that will allow you to MOVE and LINK a folder in one easy step. It focuses on MOVING the folder, then replacing the original folder with a hard link (junction) to the new location. Windows (and the user) can reference the files at the same location as before, but the actual storage of them is on the other drive. It is handy for new hard drives, and also in the case of SSDs where you may wish to redirect some folders with lots of RW activity to a conventional HDD.*

[image]
[image]
*(image source: bitsum.com)*

Answer (score 0):

One can also use the `MkLink` command that comes with Windows Vista and newer:

Move the `"%SystemRoot%\Installer"` folder (normally `"C:\Windows\Installer"`) to another place. It can be renamed, also. I suggest maintaining the same folder structure, as in `"D:\Windows\Installer"` or even `"D:\SSD junctions\Installer"`, instead of just using `"D:\Installer"`.

Then open Command Prompt and run `MkLink /j "%SystemRoot%\Installer" "<drive letter>:\new path\new folder name"`. It will create a junction point at the original `"%SystemRoot%\Installer"` folder pointing to the new location.

Since you are doing this change because of size constraints, I can tell you another way to reduce the size of the MSI Installer Cache: Instead of installing from the original .MSI file, extract all its contents to a temporary folder with `MsiExec.exe /A "path to\package.msi" TARGETDIR="%Temp%\MSI"`, then install from the reduced .MSI file inside of the temporary folder. Windows Installer will cache the smaller .MSI file containing only the installation database needed to repair, reinstall or remove the program, instead of the full .MSI file.